# slow (JavaFX) code even after reseting the repository

Tags: java, eclipse, listview, javafx-2

I just faced a strange behavior and I can't even say if it is a JavaFX specific problem, Eclipse problem or even where to start fixing first.

But first things first: I'm writing a JavaFX application (Eclipse Kepler/ Java 1.7), containing some extended ListViews. The program takes about 1sec to load.

The extended ListViews look something like that:

```
public class NewList<T extends Obj> extends ListView<T>{
    public NewList(){
//      addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>(){
//
//          @Override
//          public void handle(KeyEvent arg0) {
//              if(arg0.getText().equals(KeyCode.DELETE)){
//                  getItems().remove(getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
//              }
//          }
//      });

    }
}
```

There are also some MouseEvents (like drag and drop) inside the same constructor, and they are working as expected.
Now I want to add an EventHandler to my extended ListView (see commend in the code above).
The code takes now about 8sec to start aka 8 times longer as normal. To my surprise 90% of the loading time the program is inside the .show() method of my primaryStage (there is just one). After the loading time, the GUI is extreme slow and the cpu usage is on 100%.
Maybe the Handler is implemented wrongly and is doing some strange stuff during the whole time.

I can't find any solution or even comparable problem on the internet....but now the real problem just begun:
When I delete the Handler and run the program again, it will stay slow! So the program is in the same state as before - just still broken! That makes me crazy, because I can't see any logical explanation for that behavior.

What I have already tried:

- delete the bin folder inside the repository and build the code again (+reboot)
- reset the repository via git
- throw half of the code away and started again. At any point it worked again, unfortunately I was not able to reproduce the effect. Then I implemented the Handler again and the problems started from the beginning...

edit: it looks like there goes something wrong during the building process/updating the binarys. I deleted 99% of the code (>5k LOC), then it worked. I copy/pasted the original project back into my workspace and the hole code worked smoothly - even with the Handler on. So I can't imagine a way to produce a minimalistic setup. btw: I'm not allowed to release the complete project folder (university stuff...)

edit2: I' using win7 64bit with java64. other javaFX programs are working (even then grafic intensive oracle samples). I'm not using any JavaFX specific repository setup or builder

Comment: Are you able to replicate the problem in a small, runnable example that we can see?

Comment: What OS are you running on? Could it be a graphics driver problem?

Comment: Do you use Eclipse or Intellij? Did you try building with Maven, Ant or Gradle to see if the bug is still there (if not: it should confirm that it is indeed a build problem specific to an IDE)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I faced the same problem a few minutes ago and I think I found the source this time.

I'm running my code ALWAYS in debugging mode. To check the EventHandlers condition, I created some breakpoints in Eclipse. I also created a breakpoint at the following line of code (see above for more code)

`public void handle(KeyEvent arg0) {`

A mouseover over the breakpoint provides the following information:

> Multiple markers at this line
>
> Method breakpoint:NewList [Entry] - handle(KeyEvent)
>
> implements:javafx.event.EventHandler .handle

I don't know what is happening here exactly but I think its something like this:
I'm overriding a JavaFX EventHandler Method and the debugger has to check the breakpoint on every single JavaFX interaction/EventHandler call. So Eclipse cant handle the flood of checks in a propper time and all seems to be very slow.
To clear that out: the breakpoint itself does not have to be called at any time, just the existing of it is enough to cause the problems.

Deactivating the breakpoint or running the application in a non-debugging mode will fix all problems. I think it should be a good idea to avoid all entry-breakpoints in any kind of Listener/EventHandler :)